# Questions about performance jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, performance

I had a question about performance ?

Is it better to have the two images written in html, one hidden and one displayed, and with jQuery change the display of both (to hide the one displayed, and show the hided one) ?

```
<img id="1" style="display:none;" src="img1.png" />
<img id="2" src="img2.png" />
$('#1').onclick(function (){
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  $("#2").css('display', 'inline-block');
});
$('#2').onclick(function (){
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
  $("#1").css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

or is it better to change the src of the image ?

```
$('#1').onclick(function (){
  if ($(this).attr('src') == 'img1.png')
    $(this).attr('src', 'img2.png');
  else
    $(this).attr('src', 'img1.png');
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: one performance problem is jQuery doesn't have an `onclick` method

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the src is probably a better approach since the image request will be made on demand (if the click event was triggered) if the user does not click it, then you save one *unnecessary* request.

However, if the image needs to be changed multiple times with clicks this can be a lot of *unnecessary* requests.

An alternative would be is to create 2 images in the DOM and swap based on the click

```
var $img1 = $('<img>', {
    src: 'img1.png'
});
var $img2 = $('<img>', {
    src: 'img2.png'
});


$('#1').click(function (){
  if ($(this).attr('src') == 'img1.png')
    $(this).html($img2);
  else
    $(this).html($img1);
});
```

Comment: Most modern browsers will cache the two images so you will most likely get a maximum of two requests when you flip the `src`. The downside to this approach is the second image may take a while to load and might not be available immediately on click. So the answer to the OP's question really depends on which tradeoff you prefer to make.

Comment: Or use a sprite/background image and just tweak the position to show the second image.  That's probably fastest.